# ImageView updating seconds after progressDialog

Tags: android, imageview, progressdialog

I am using asynckTask to decode a file and onPostExecute I setImageBitmap and call progressDialog.dismiss() but after the progressDialog is dismissed the imageView take a few seconds to show the image. What I want is the progressDialog to disappear only when the image view is ready for the user. My code is below:

```
    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private String mainImageString;
    private Context context;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public MyTask(ImageView imageView, Context mContext) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        context = mContext;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(MyClass.this, "Progress Dialog Title Text","Process Description Text", true);
    }
    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        mainImageString = params[0];
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mainImageString);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the problem is because the bitmap is kinda large. That's why I'm decoding using AsynckTask. But I though progressDialog.dismiss(); should only be called after imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting your Bitmap basically you are "building" it on the UI thread. What I recommend is to call setImageBitmap in your doInBackground callback and then dismiss the dialog.

Comment: I can't call setImageBitmap on doInBackground. I get the error: "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...

```
     @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
        final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        if (imageView != null) {
               imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
               handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               public void run() { 
                 progressDialog.dismiss();
                 } 
               }, 1000); //time for image to appear in image view
        }
    }
```

Please note this is not a foolproof way..but this what-easy way-currently I can think of..

Other hack I can think about is to extend `ImageView` and override `onDraw()`.call super() in onDraw(),once the call to super() returns then dismiss the dialog box.This is more accurate way of doing it.

something like this:

```
onDraw(){
  super();
  onDismissDialogBox()//send an even to activity to dismiss dialog box 
}
```